# Using Embedded coder to generate subsystem level code?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to know whether embedded  coder be used to generate subsystem level code only and not the whole model, The model i am working on has multiple complex logic running on a memory constrained Real time system.

I want to generate the logic for a subsystem and analyze it, before proceeding to others.
Because these systems are interdependent,reducing complexity at a later stage in development would be a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe so. if you right-click on a subsystem, you should have an option "Generate code" or similar.

Comment: I tried it, there was no option for code generation as such, does it require to be modified in some way for that option to appear?

Comment: The subsystem in question needs to be atomic. See this question http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/96190-how-do-i-convert-blocks-in-simulink-library-to-c-c-code-in-simulink-7-4-r2009b on MATLAB Answers.

Comment: I think it's "Build subsystem" rather than "Generate code".